# entity framework 6 изменить тип ключа с int на string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Использую code first. Возникла следующая проблема.

Создал модель:

```
class Collector
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

После решил изменить тип ключа с `int` на `string`:

```
class Collector
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Id {get; set;}
}
```

Но получаю такую ошибку при обновлении базы:

> Identity column 'Id' must be of data type int, bigint, smallint,
>   tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0, and constrained to
>   be nonnullable.

В общем то понятно, изначально ключ создался как `identity`, теперь при обновлении базы у нас выполняется следующий скрипт:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Collectors] ALTER COLUMN [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL
```

И SQL Server говорит нам, что `identity` к `string` не применить.

Как "победить" ситуацию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если CodeFirst то вы должны создать migration script:

- создаете новую колонку с новым типом; - переносите данные;
- удаляете старую колонку со старым типом;

Comment: Спасибо, я как-то сразу об этом не подумал. Пытался решить через изменение самой модели.:)